# Regex - indexof - split and replace how should I apply them correctly?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, split

am trying to replace qty value in an addtocart href, something similar to :`en/products/webshop/cart/{$item->id}/{variant->id}/{$quantity}/name.htm`, this is taking place in frontend, ignore the curly brackets since those will return plain integers using smarty template engine.

am changing the addtocart link upon user selecting a different qty value, which by default in the link it's '1'. have activeqty and addtocartlink variables. I need to replace the value between the last /value/name.htm

tried multiple examples after reading off here and w3schools. Also tried using: `replace('/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)\/(.*?)/',activeqty);`

Thanks guys, would appreciate a brief explanation of the proposed solutions so it would let me understand and be able to use it in different situations.

Comment: .* will match slashes.
[^\]* will be better as it matches everything but slashes

Comment: Normally, I'd split by `"/"`, but I'd be careful in this case, since you seems to be able to insert code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var regexp = /^([^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*$)/ ;
your_string = your_string.replace( regexp , '\1/1/\3' ); // replace quantity with 1
qty = parseInt( your_string.replace( regexp , '\2' ) ); // get the quantity
// function to increase quantity :
your_string = your_string.replace( regexp, function(match, p1,p2,p3, offset, s)
    {
        return p1 +'/' + (parseInt(p2)+1) + '/' + p3;
    } );
```

[demo](http://regex101.com/r/kO1sJ0/3) 
[demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/o507j9ff/)

Comment: Am I interpreting it correctly that the substition is expecting the pattern to match two 1's? since the variantid is dynamic and might not be 1. Btw thanks for the awesome link to regex101, still am trying to adjust it to my requirement since the string isn't changing in js for me, although on regex101 it is.

Comment: no no. It replaces with \1/1\3 : that means : \1 = the content of the first brackets ( and ), then the string "/1", then \3 = the content of the third brackets

Comment: then again, what if the user would have already selected another qty by mistake, it would only work first time. thus I can't use a particular value as a comparison, but instead I must use the pattern so I always change anything between the last two forward slashes, and this would enable the user to keep changin quantities with no problems.

Comment: i thought you wanted to replace {$quantity} with "1". What do you want to replace it with ?

Comment: ignore the curly brackets, just consider this path: text/text/text/text/text/integer/integer/integer/text.htm, I will store the qty chosen from select menu in var activeqty. and upon using qty from select I update var addtocartlink which has the path stored, having the activeqty var replace the last integer or anything that is found between the last two forward slashes.

Comment: addtocartlink = 'text/text/text/text/text/integer/integer/integer/text.htm'; activeqty = 4 or any value chosen from select menu, then addtocarlink = addtocartlink.replace(regex'+activeqty+'lastpattern);